# Weird error when I try to launch Ubuntu in a virtual machine

Tags: command-line, unity, permissions, root, vmware

When I logged into Ubuntu today, everything worked fine at first. But then small things started acting up. For example, a file on my desktop had become read-only, and if I tried to change it to read/write, it would say I had invalid permissions. For some reason, when I tried to launch Firefox, I got an error saying that I already had a session open, and I needed to close that session.

When I tried restarting Ubuntu, all I got was a CLI with this error:

[image]

If anyone can help me solve this problem, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: It appears your filesystem got corrupted.

Comment: Type `fsck /dev/sda1` and just continue accepting(option y, which is yes) until it finishes. After that type `reboot`. It should boot up normally.